# как экранировать текст полученный с CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

как можно экранировать данные полученные с ckeditor, затем передать через json
Js:

```
var editor = $(this).find(".custom-tabs__textarea").attr("id"),
    txt = CKEDITOR.instances[editor].getData(),

tabsName.push({
    text: txt
 });
```

вот такое получаеться на выходе сейчас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Экранировать в каком смысле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ, если вы хотите получить на выходе читаемую строку без спецсимволов.

```js
    tabsName = []
    var txt = document.createElement('div');
    txt.innerHTML = "&#39;"; // CKEDITOR.instances[editor].getData() это тут пропишите. 
    tabsName.push({
    text: txt.innerText
    });
    alert(tabsName[0].text)
```